# Menus in android not working

Tags: java, android, menu, android-menu

I am trying to create a menu with two items 'help' and 'about'. I have written the code. It has no errors but the code is not working. I have also added the activity in manifest file. Here is my AndroidMenusActivity code:

```
package com.easy.convert;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class AndroidMenusActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

// Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml)
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected
 * Identify single menu item by it's id
 * */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_help:
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);
        dialog.setTitle("Help");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_about:
        Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(this);
        dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);
        dialog1.setTitle("About");
        dialog1.setCancelable(true);
        dialog1.show();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }    
}
```

menu.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.easy.convert ">
<!-- Single menu item 
     Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
-->
<item android:id="@+id/menu_help"
      android:icon="@drawable/help"
      android:title="Help" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_about"
      android:icon="@drawable/about"
      android:title="About" />

</menu>
```

I want menu on every activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.easy.convert ">
<!-- Single menu item 
     Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
-->
<item android:id="@+id/menu_help"
      android:icon="@drawable/help"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:title="Help" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_about"
      android:icon="@drawable/about"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:title="About" />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here:

```
// Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml)
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Your can check here:[Google Document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Hope that help!

Comment: Please make sure that you push the menu.xml code to the menu folder. 
And try to change the namespace:
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.easy.convert "
to:
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: Oh! I try to copy your code and test in my device. That work for me.

Answer (score 0):

use the following code to All your activity.

```
      @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Event Handling for Individual menu item selected
     * Identify single menu item by it's id
     * */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
     {

    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_help:
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);
        dialog.setTitle("Help");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_about:
        Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(this);
        dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.aboutus);
        dialog1.setTitle("About");
        dialog1.setCancelable(true);
        dialog1.show();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
```

Comment: which device you are testing? Because hardware menu button is deprecated.

Comment: I am testing on my Micromax Canvas HD phone (Android 4.2.1)

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure about your device. but http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html this helps you.